# Where can I find CMS pages from magento 2?

Tags: magento2, migration

I accidentally overwrote CMS pages when I migrated from M1 to M2.
I still have the backup of the old M2. So my question is, where can I find the file location of the M2 CMS pages?

Comment: check under content > pages

Comment: No I can't because they are gone. I have the backup. I'm thinking more like in folder file location in public_html.

Comment: do you have M2 database backup ?

Comment: Yes. Currently I'm trying to overwrite all old cms tables with new ones. So I think that should do the trick right?

Comment: Yes, just dump table "cms_page" and "cms_page_store" from old database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have old database backup, You can just copy `cms_page` and `cms_page_store` table and import in new database.

> just dump table "cms_page" and "cms_page_store" form old database

Hope above will help!

Comment: if anybody down vote, should take bother to write comment why down voting!..:)

Answer (score 1):

Just open your database managers like PHPMyAdmin or [adminer](https://www.adminer.org/) and search for a table with the name cms_page (in your dumped back-up). And check every page via its name, for example, 404 Not Found. After this, you can see a column with the name "content" - its the content of this page, you can edit it. Screenshot example below.
[image]